# R markdown: problems with Latex headers

Tags: latex, r-markdown

When I setup a header by using a custom .sty file and the fancyhdr package, the header text is automatically formatted and the text is taken from the first header defined in the .Rmd file, and I cannot override this behavior. For instance, I have the following R markdown file

````
---
output:
  pdf_document:
    includes:
      in_header: report.sty
    keep_tex: yes
geometry: tmargin=2cm, bmargin=2.5cm
classoption: a4paper
---

\pagenumbering{gobble}

# Behavioural profile of your dog

blah... blah...

```{r echo}

  # Some R code here...

```
````

And this is the .sty file:

```
%
% This file must be saved with UTF-8 encoding, otherwise pandoc will complain
% for instance about nordic characters.
%

\usepackage{palatino}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} % sans serif
\fontfamily{ppl}\selectfont
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{eso-pic, rotating, graphicx, calc}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}

% Code to add a vertical gray band in the inner margin :
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\definecolor{colorMarge}{RGB}{242,242,245}
\newlength{\distance}
\setlength{\distance}{0.0in} % 0.5in
\newlength{\rulethickness}
\setlength{\rulethickness}{0.3in} % 1pt
\newlength{\ruleheight}
\setlength{\ruleheight}{11in} % Longueur de la ligne
\newlength{\xoffset}
\newlength{\yoffset}
\setlength{\yoffset}{0.5\dimexpr\paperheight-\ruleheight}

\AddToShipoutPicture{%
        \ifodd\value{page}%
                \setlength{\xoffset}{\distance}%
        \else
                \setlength{\xoffset}{\dimexpr\paperwidth-\rulethickness-\distance}%
        \fi
        \AtPageLowerLeft{\put(\LenToUnit{\xoffset},\LenToUnit{\yoffset}){\color{colorMarge}\rule{\rulethickness}{\ruleheight}}}%
}

\newcommand{\sidewaysText}{R Development Core Team (2008). R: A language and environment for statistical computing. R Foundation for Statistical Computing, Vienna, Austria. ISBN 3-900051-07-0, URL http://www.R-project.org.}

%\newlength{\swtLen}
%\setlength{\swtLen}{\widthof{\sidewaysText}}
%\newlength{\swtPos}
%\setlength{\swtPos}{\yoffset}
%\addtolength{\swtPos}{0.5\swtLen}

%\newlength{\swtPos}
%\setlength{\swtPos}{350em}

\AddToShipoutPicture{\put(5,10){\rotatebox{90}{\scalebox{0.8}{\sidewaysText}}}}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\chead{I want this header}
\lfoot{\scriptsize
Here is some footer text.}
```

But this is the output:

[image]

As you can see, the "THIS IS SOME HEADER" appears as part of the header in capital letters, italics and aligned to the right. How can avoid this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After loading [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) in `report.sty`, clear all the headers/footers *first* using `\fancyhf{}`. That is,

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}% Header rule
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}% Footer rule
\chead{I want this header}% Centre header
\lfoot{\scriptsize Here is some footer text.}% Left footer
```

You've only set `\chead` and `\lfoot`, so the other four components of the header/footer (three for each: `l`eft, `c`entre, `r`ight) may still contain content specifications... whatever they may be. `\fancyhf{}` clears all of these so you can set them as needed.

Of course, if you only want to clear the `r`ight `head`er, you can also execute `\rhead{}`.

Comment: Hi, thanks! Sorry for the delayed reply. It worked perfectly.

Comment: @Werner Thanks for your response. How would you suppress the "This is Some Header" in the body of the page below the header. If you wanted the section title only in the header not the body.

Comment: @user3022875: Using `# This is Some Header` sets a `\section` in LaTeX. A `\section` also calls `\sectiomark`, which sets a "mark" in the header. By default, this is done via a macro called `\leftmark`. You can void what `\sectionmark` is doing by adding to `report.sty` the following line of code: `\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{}}`.

Comment: @Werner thanks for your response. Can you see here for my example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57983035/removing-section-in-rmarkdown-doc  \AtBegin... still keeps the print in the body