# removing section in rmarkdown doc

Tags: r-markdown

I'd like to have the section titles in the header not the body of the page. \fancyhead[C]...puts the section title in the header but how do you suppress the body printing of the section?

````
---
title: "Untitled"
classoption: landscape
output: 
  pdf_document:
    number_sections: false
    dev: pdf
    keep_tex: false
    toc: yes
header-includes:
- \usepackage{fancyhdr}
- \usepackage{etoolbox}
- \pagestyle{fancy}
- \fancyhead[L]{left}
- \fancyhead[R]{right}
- \fancyhead[C]{   \nouppercase{\leftmark}   }

---




```{r setup, include=FALSE}
    knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)  
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```

\newpage

# Including Plots

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.

\newpage

# page 3

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r pressured, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.
````

Comment: please elaborate on what you expect (in which document format) and what you get: give example of the expected and of what you get.